# Flutter Supabase has problem to handle the onAuthStateChange event with dynamic widget

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, supabase

Hello I am currently looking to change my project to supabase with real SQL.

In my firebase project I had an Checker which checks the current authstate which always returns a User?.

Now I try to replicate this in supabase but it is not working. As I try to logout the screen does not render to example the login screen.

[image]

This I my implementation in Firebase. The authState returns the current User?. When I invoke this in Supabase it only is called when the State changes.

Does anyone of you already had this issue ?

I made a little Example of supabase, but I think it is not nice [image]

Comment: Supabase does return whatever the latest auth state is when you listen to `onAuthStateChanged` just like Firebase. Make sure you are using the latest supabase_flutter library!

Comment: Yeah installed it a few days ago, it only went into when I change the state not everytime

Comment: Please describe what exactly you mean by `not everytime`. `onAuthStateChange` does indeed fire an event when you first listen to it, and will fire event anytime the auth state changes, but when exactly is it not firing for you?

Comment: Only when the state changes when icall the Function then not

Comment: What exactly do you mean "when I call the Function hen not"? Which function are you calling? Could edit your question and add the code for when you are calling the function?

Comment: Onauthstatechanges listen it only goes in when thewstate changes